# Dynamic partial name using slim and Rails 4 & getting Partial Name is Not Valid Ruby Identifier Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, partials, slim-lang

I am building a Rails 4 blogging app and using Slim.
I am trying to dynamically set the partial name using my 'img_style' column in my Post table.  This will call different partials based on different enumerated 'image styles'.
 
**view**

```
= render = 'img_style_{#@post.img_style}'
```

This should produce the equivalent to:

```
= render = 'img_style_1'
```

I'd like this it to be able to render my partial called  **'_img_style_1.html.slim'**

Right now, with the code I have, it just renders this error on the screen:

```
There is an Error: The partial name (img_style_{#@post.img_style}) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscores.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby `String`s defined with single quotes (`''`) do not allow expression substitution. You need to use double quotes (`""`) instead, and also use the proper substitution syntax (`#` before `{`):

```
"img_style_#{@post.img_style}"
```

**ETA** Relatedly, and perhaps you've already done this, but I would make sure that `img_style` only includes values for which partials are defined using a validation, e.g.:

```
validates_inclusion_of :img_style, in: [1,2,3]
```